# Equivalent of Iterator.Remove in Kotlin HashMap?

Tags: kotlin

Sorry if this is a dumb question-- but in java I am used to doing something like the following:

```
Iterator whatever = entrySet.iterator()
while (whatever.hasNext()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == 3) {
            whatever.remove(whatever.next().key)
        }
    }
}
```

(Pseudocode and the logic makes no sense)

However, the "remove" function doesn't exist for a hashmap in Kotlin. I understand you can use removeIf for a single condition, but I want to loop through a bunch of different conditions before I decide what to remove-- all without dodging a concurrent modification exception.

What is the way to do this in Kotlin?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: *However, the "remove" function doesn't exist for a hashmap in Kotlin* Yes it does (but of course, just like in Java, it doesn't take any argument). Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Here's mine: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/e28de17572b6370e4171d311ea5db780

Comment: Ah, I completely tweaked on that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin you can use `removeIf` on mutable map entries without accessing the iterator explicitly.

```
val entrySet = HashMap<String, String>()
entrySet.entries.removeIf { 
  // some predicate 
}
```

will remove all entries that match the predicate

Comment: "removeIf" requires API >= 24, because it's from java.util.Collection. We should use "removeAll(predicate: (T) -> Boolean)" from kotlin.collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
val addedItems = HashMap<String, Int>()

fun main() {
    addedItems["Apple"] = 3
    addedItems["Lemon"] = 4

    println(addedItems)

    addedItems.values.removeAll { it == 4 }        //or remove by keys ".keys.removeAll{}
    println(addedItems)
}
```

Output:

```
{Apple=3, Lemon=4}
{Apple=3}
```